# Setting Heroku Config Var with contents from Google Cloud Service Account Keyfile

Tags: node.js, heroku, google-cloud-platform

I have a web app that I'm trying to deploy with Heroku. I'm using the Google Cloud Node.js library for accessing google cloud storage. I have the following at the top of my server file:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
  projectId: 'my-project-ID',
  credentials: process.env.GCS_KEYFILE
});
```

GCS_KEYFILE is an configuration variable that I've set using the Heroku command line tools using `heroku config:set GCS_KEYFILE="$(< /my/file.json)"`

Checking the dashboard to make sure that worked confirms the contents of the JSON file have been set to a config var. Screenshot looks like this:
[image]

The error I get when I try to do anything with `gcs` is:

```
Error: Could not authenticate request 
The incoming JSON object does not contain a client_email field
```

Which makes no sense because it clearly does. The json itself is fine; I took the download directly from Google Cloud without modifying it. I've tried using `keyFileName` in my `const gcs` declaration but I get a `ENAMETOOLONG` error (plus [the docs say](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node) thats for specifying the path to the JSON file anyway). It works locally when I use `keyFileName` and specify the path to the JSON file so I'm pretty sure the JSON itself not the issue.

Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error? Or is there a better way to handle JSON Keyfiles from Google on Heroku?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Environment variables on heroku, or anywhere, are strings.

If that google api constructor takes a JSON object you may need to do something like this to convert it back to JSON:

```
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({
  projectId: 'my-project-ID',
  credentials: JSON.parse(process.env.GCS_KEYFILE)
});
```

Comment: Ugh, so simple! Thanks for the quick reply, I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a helpful heroku buildpack for this

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/buyersight/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack.git
```

`--index 1` is because "The buildpack for the primary language of your app should be the last buildpack added," so if you have other buildpacks be careful of that.